# Drop Down List with Css

Tags: html, css

Here Available Courses for Alert drop down iam want float it to left and iam not getting the background please heal me and the important thing is i just want to add changes to just that particular li

```
<style type="text/css">
    #ddmenu > li:first-child ul{
        display: none;
        margin-left:1px;
        padding:10px 15px
    }
    #ddmenu > li:hover ul{
        display: block;
        float:none;
        position: absolute;
        list-style-type: none;   
        text-decoration:none;
    }
    #ddmenu > li:hover ul li a{
        text-decoration:none;
    }
</style>
```

```
<ul class="nav pull-right" id="ddmenu">
    <li class="menu"><?php echo '<img src="theme/alert.png" alt="alert" height="42" width="42">' ?>
        <ul id="dropdown">
            <li><?php echo'<a href="#">Available courses</a>' ?></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li></li>
    <li><?php echo $OUTPUT->page_heading_menu(); ?></li>
    <li class="navbar-text"><?php echo $OUTPUT->login_info() ?></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you are trying to give background color for drop down and left align.

Try below code.

Hope below code will be helpful.

```
<ul class="nav pull-right" id="ddmenu">
    <li class="menu"><a href="#">Menu</a>
        <ul id="dropdown">
            <li><a href="#">Available courses</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Menu</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Menu</a></li>
    <li class="navbar-text"><a href="#">Menu</a></li>
 </ul>
```

CSS

```
#ddmenu > li:first-child ul {
    display: none;
    margin-left: 1px;
    padding: 10px 15px;
}

#ddmenu > li {
    position: relative;
    list-style: none;
}

#ddmenu > li a {
    padding: 5px;
    background: #ddd;
    display: block;
}

#ddmenu > li:hover ul {
    display: block;
    float: none;
    left: 50px;
    top: 0;
    position: absolute;
    list-style-type: none;
    text-decoration: none;
    z-index: 999;
    padding: 0;
}

#ddmenu > li:hover ul li a {
    text-decoration: none;
}

#ddmenu li ul {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

#ddmenu li li a {
    background: red;
    padding: 5px;
    color: #fff;
    display: block;
}
```

[JSFIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/shanidkv/Lwj4spbL/1/)

Comment: its working but Available Course is not getting in one line its displaying in two lines ""

Comment: Updated fiddle and above answer. please check